# Resizable divs within a container w/o Jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok - So I am kind of struggling with this. I am trying to achieve something pretty straight forward I think. I need 3 resizable divs within a fixed width container div without using Jquery. The resize needs to occur for all divs only horizontally as they all have the parent divs height. Here is the layout

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="m1">M1</div>
        <div id="m2">M2</div>
        <div id="m3">M3</div>
    </div>
```

My object here is to wrap this into a ReactJS component and therefore not wanting to muddy the waters with Jquery. Any help/direction would be most appreciated. If someone can mock up something like this in React, that would be awesome too! :)

Not sure whether this can be a CSS only solution but I am open to ideas

Thanks

Comment: okay i am not 100% sure what your solution should look like at the end, could you take a picture what the result should be like?

Comment: Hm.. CSS Solution? give container 100% width, give each child div 33% width?

Comment: Why would the inner divs resize if the outer div is fixed width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't exactly clear to me, if your container div is fixed width (as in a constant value) then your child divs should not resize dynamically no matter what the width of anything beyond the container is.

The only other way I could interpret your question, is that you need some sort of grid system, where you can drag to resize the width of the child divs within the confines of the container. In that case, I might be wrong but I don't think the solution is that simple, you might want to take a look at this package: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

More specifically, their simplest implementation allows you to define a fixed width container (1200 in this case) like so:

```
  <ReactGridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
    <div key={'a'}>a</div>
    <div key={'b'}>b</div>
    <div key={'c'}>c</div>
  </ReactGridLayout>
```

Comment: NKJo28 - You sir are a scholar and a gentleman. May your tribe prosper. This is precisely what I was looking to achieve "Being able to resize the width of divs within a confined parent div".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the parent `div`'s size and then have the inner `div`s automatically resize based on the parent `div` you can use the flex box layout which you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In your case you can set the styling of the first div to:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

And for the children (in your case identified by `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`) you need to set the css property `flex-grow` to how big do you want it to be relative to the others. Say, if you want `m1` and `m2` to have the same size and `m3` to be twice as big, you would do the following:

```
#m1, #m2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#m3 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to consider renaming the ids/classes.

In case you are looking to get the exact size of the parent of a `div` you can do this as following:

```
render() {
  return <div ref="node"></div>
}

componentDidMount() {
   const parentWidth = this.refs['node'].parentNode.clientWidth;
   // Do whatever you need here (like setting state of the react component)
}
```